# SQL Error during Shopware 6 installation when choosing CHF as default currency

Tags: installation, shopware, mysql-error-1451

For a Swiss based client I'm trying to install a new Shopware 6 store. During the configuration phase I get a SQL-Integrity error when changing the default currency to CHF. However when I'm trying to install with the default settings (i.e. EUR as default currency) the installation succeeds.

Here is the screenshot of the settings:
[image]

Here is the error shown:
[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that the installation with EUR works flawlessly.
Please doublecheck and make sure you tried with the same environment.

Please also make sure that the database is empty before the installation.

If so, this clearly is a bug and should be reported at

https://issues.shopware.com/